# stof returning 0 for object, works fine for normal variables

Tags: c++, class, vector, methods

I have a vector that stores some values, and a class Weather with some methods. One of the methods is to convert a string to a float using stof, and do a calculation on that new value and return it. I see that stof works for one of my independent variables that doesn't belong to a class, but when I call this method that does stof on the string passed inside and returns that float value after calculation, it returns a 0. Can someone explain why this is?

Main.cpp:

```
cout << "Before converting: " << solar1 << '\n';
windlog2.solar.SetSolar(solar1);
cout << "After converting: " << windlog2.solar.GetSolar() << '\n';
```

Weather.cpp:

```
float Weather::convertSolar(string solar1){

    float newValue = 0;

    newValue = stof(solar1);

    newValue = ((newValue)*(1/6))/1000;

    solar = newValue;

    return solar;

}
```

In my cout statements, for the Before Converting values they are the same as the string I use, and the After Converting values are all 0.

Comment: This could be an artifact of simplifying for the question, but that expression could be written more simply as `newValue/6000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(1/6)` is `0` because it's an integer division. Thus everything becomes zero.

```
newValue = ((newValue) * (1.f / 6.f)) / 1000.f;
```

should work.

Comment: You're right, it does. Silly me. Thank you for that!